# What is this tool for carrying pots called?

Tags: identification, tools

Landscapers were using them to carry 2 5-gallon landscape pots in each hand.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this tool is specially made for lifting and carrying just gardening pots. There are many similarly shaped tools for lifting and carrying objects of different shapes and sizes (most results I've found show similar tools for lifting hot pots/kitchenware). I think those are generally considered to be some kind of (slip)joint type pliers.

Comment: These have a grabbing angle that is distinctly different from those used for kitchen pots. I'll look into "slip joint pliers"

Answer (score 1):

A company called Vargo sells something very similar they call a "Titanium Pot Lifter" but when this is resold on a major online store it becomes a "Titanium Pot Gripper"; I hesitate to provide a link since it is commercial but I'm sure you can do a search. A pot 'lifter' could be a number of things, so maybe the 'gripper' is a better label, being both descriptive and specific to the application.

The function seems to be to ease the work of moving pots, where normally the strain goes to the thumb and two or three fingertips and transfers the weight to the palm of the hand. I'm sure if you are unloading a delivery of a semi truck load of pots this tool would be one of your best friends.

Comment: These "pot lifters" intended for handling hot cooking pots are quite common. They would not be nearly as useful as the pictured tool, which has much longer handles which would reduce required bending over. The picture tool also offers a different "angle of attack" which is more suited to carrying pots hanging down at arms length.